# ng-click inside directive not working with infowindow

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, events, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I wrote a directive that displays information about places.

**HTML CODE**

```
    <div class="small-12 columns">
        <h1>{{place.info.title}}</h1>
    </div>
    ...
    <button class="success left" ng-click="test()">test</button>
```

**Directive Code**

```
app.directive('infowindow', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'pages/infowindow.html'
    }
});
```

I try add this directive to infowindow in service:

**Controller Code**

```
var contentString = '<infowindow></infowindow>';
var compiled = $compile(contentString)(scope);

var test = function() {
    console.log('test clicked');
};

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, scope, place) {
    return function(){
        scope.place = place;
        scope.test = test;
        scope.$apply();
        infowindow.setContent(compiled[0].innerHTML);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    };
})(marker, scope, list[i]));
```

And save some variables to scope for its use in directive template.

The problem that `ng-click="test()"` in directive is not working, 
but display other angular directives like `{{place.info.title}}` (interpolution directive), `ng-hide`, etc. works fine!

If I directly add my directive as `<infowindow></infowindow>` on html markup all this works!

Help will be appreciated. Apologize for my bad English. 
Thanks.

**UPD:** simple example of my code in plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/jsFWXJyWo8acwP4jVQKs

Comment: does console giving any error?

Comment: use $cope.test. ng-click directive always search method in scope

Comment: Console silent, no errors.
i'm use $scope, only $scope in service in argument look like `scope`.

And i bind `test` with scope: `scope.test = test;`

Comment: that means you are passing scope to your service?

Comment: Yes, as parameter in controller.

Comment: don't pass whole scope to service. you should consume the service from controller.. and update scope from controller itself .

Comment: I know this bad style for code. You can see simple example my code in plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/jsFWXJyWo8acwP4jVQKs

Comment: I'm taking a look at it, I'll give my best to solve it

Comment: Thank you I will be very grateful to you!

Comment: checkout my answer..i think i did what you want..hurrey..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use compiled element `compiled[0]` instead of `compiled[0].innerHtml`.
Only binding innerHtml may loss two way binding of AngularJS.

**CODE**

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, scope, place) {
    return function(){
        scope.place = place;
        scope.test = test;
        scope.$apply();
        infowindow.setContent(compiled[0]); //replaced compiled[0].innerHtml with compiled object
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    };
})(marker, scope, list[i]));
```

Updated **[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/N3nmHntPKtdMzhIU9t5s?p=preview)** with style issue resolved.

Comment: Yes! This is really works! ng-click works fine, but after insert google maps infowindow not correctly displayed :(
You can see that here: http://plnkr.co/edit/mI5vIMyUQ0gFcbw5SzLZ

Comment: @YuriHaichuk  After a lot of try i can do that css somewhat ok..now its your turn to make it good. Thanks. Feeling glad to help.

Comment: @YuriHaichuk  if the answer does helps you. Don't forget to vote up and marking as correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help an quick answers! I marked your answer as correct, but i don't have 15 reputation for vote up, sorry :(

Comment: @YuriHaichuk  It's ok pal, Feeling glad to resolve your problem. Learnt some google API stuff because of this :)

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you should not generate html code within a service or a controller. Since this will be a DOM manipulation and should only be done with a directive. 
As you said using `<infowindow></infowindow>`directly works, and that is how you should use it.

But to come back to your problem
    `ng-click="test()"` doesn't work because it is not bound to the $scope. Try changing you code to

```
$scope.test = function() {
    console.log('test clicked');
};
```

Comment: I repeat one my comment:
I'm use $scope, only $scope in service in argument look like `scope`. And i bind test with scope: `scope.test = test;`

Comment: I generate html code in service because infowindow content displays dynamicly when I clicked on a marker on the map and after click infowindow will open.
Yes, i said that using `<infowindow></infowindow>` directly works, but i don't need. I did it just for check.